# My SQL Alter function error

Tags: mysql, function

This is MySql code Alter Function

```
DELIMITER $$
ALTER FUNCTION Tepat(tgl_permohonan DATETIME, total_hari_kerja INT)
    RETURNS INT WITH EXECUTE AS CALL AS BEGIN
    DECLARE jumlah_hari INT, i INT, selisih INT;
    SET i = 0;
    SET jumlah_hari = 0;
    WHILE (i < total_hari_kerja) 
    BEGIN 
    IF (EXTRACT(WEEK FROM tgl_permohonan) != 6) AND (EXTRACT(WEEK FROM tgl_permohonan) != 5)
    BEGIN
        SET i = i + 1;
    END IF;
    SET jumlah_hari = jumlah_hari + 1;
    SET tgl_permohonan = DATE_ADD(tgl_permohonan, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END;
    SET selisih = DATEDIFF(tgl_permohonan, NOW());
    IF selisih <= 0
    BEGIN
    SET selisih = 0;
    END IF;
    RETURN selisih;
    END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

getting the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(tgl_permohonan DATETIME, total_hari_kerja INT) RETURNS INT WITH
>   EXECUTE AS CALL AS BEGIN' at line 1

Answer (score 4):

In order to change a stored function in MySQL you **have to** drop and recreate it.

```
DROP FUNCTION Tepat;
CREATE FUNCTION Tepat(...
```

`ALTER FUNCTION` only let you change the characteristics (like COMMENT or DEFINER) of a function.

> **[ALTER FUNCTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-function.html)**
>   This statement can be used to change the characteristics of a stored function. More than one change may be specified in an ALTER FUNCTION statement. However, you cannot change the parameters or body of a stored function using this statement; to make such changes, you must drop and re-create the function using DROP FUNCTION and CREATE FUNCTION.

Comment: I 've tried it, but also error 
#1305 - FUNCTION dtkp.Tepat does not exist 

Help me!! :)

Comment: @Hidayat: You need to drop and re-create the function if it has any functional changes by definition. This is mandatory. And, btw, there are several other errors in your code. Trace and fix them out.

Comment: @Hidayat: As I already mentioned, there are several other errors in your code. You have to fix them. Read, and understand error stack message and make necessary changes.

Comment: @RevinderReddy, ok thanks this function has successfully
Thanks for your help :)